# How do I play Offline Co-Op?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

**How can I play offline co-op on Star Wars Battlefront on Xbox One?**

I have been able to play Multiplayer Offline, Player 1 vs Player 2, but how do I play Player 1 + Player 2 VS AI Enemy?

Step-by-step instructions, please. I don't have an internet connection for my Xbox. Do I need to be online for this?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I fixed your tags and title, and spruced up the text a bit. Battlefront has a co-op mode. I don't have my game with me to write you step-by-step instructions in a full answer. Try playing 'survival' with a friend in the battles section. Here's an article about it: http://www.theverge.com/2015/11/17/9746710/star-wars-battlefront-co-op-split-screen-ps4-xbox-pc

Comment: DC, Thanks for that. Yeah, i must be missing something because I could not see those modes.. Do you need to have internet connection to access those menus?

Please let me know what I should be seeing when im in the game.. I'm not missing a download patch am I? As mentioned, i dont have a web connection for my xbox..

Comment: Ah, sorry. I meant to check last night. Slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to co-op in battles or hero battles, but in the training missions and survival there should be an option to the right of start and online co-op that says, "Split screen Co-op". Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In Battlefront II, You have to go to the Arcade menu, where you can choose between versus or co-op. After selecting co-op, you can then choose battle scenarios, where you play as set heroes or villains, or custom arcade, where you can choose team battle or starfighter battle.
This feature isnt present in Battlefront I as far as i'm aware